# Running SDK Helloworld.c without UART Cable

Tags: sdk, fpga, xilinx

I have a board with Xilinx FPGA ultrascale+, with no UART Cable.

So far, I programmed the board by generating bitstream, Scped to the board via Ethernet cable, loaded the bitstream to FPGA, to program.

At the moment, I am writing code, which needs to use SDK.

SDK gives several default templates such as Helloworld.c where you can program the board easily by just clicking the Green "Run" button. However, it requires UART connection as pre-requisite.

So...Is it possible to run SDK code for my FPGA-board with no UART cable?

1. For example, is there a way to click the green Run button in the SDK code via Ethernet cable connection?
2. Or is there a way to somehow wrap the SDK C code in my bitstream? and send the bitstream to FPGAboard via Ethernet cable to program it?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can, I use it all the time. It is one of the settings inside a CPU window which re-directs the UART communication to the Xilinx programming JTAG and from there to a local SDK window. This is a comment because I have the details at work and, today being Saturday, I am not there.

Comment: Could you post full answer, how to do the redirection from UART to Ethernet (not JTAG) in a bit more detail? I need your help!. Thank you.

Comment: We may have a miscommunication. I was assuming you where running SDK with a remotely connected FPGA board and that you are communicating with the board real time through a Xilinx debug connection. If not my solution will not work